# login con javaFx y MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, javafx, fxml

Soy nuevo usando JavaFX y estoy intentando hacer un login conectado a la base de datos

Launcher del Programa

```
public class Login extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
       try {
              AnchorPane root = 
    (AnchorPane)FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/view/login.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
 }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
    }

 }
```

login.fxml

```
    <AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="325.0" prefWidth="443.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.102" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="login.AppController">
       <children>
       <ImageView fitHeight="361.0" fitWidth="612.0" layoutX="-169.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
     <image>
        <Image url="@../Imagenes/a2e12f1e7a28db012347c4bd2ce6894c.jpg" />
     </image>
  </ImageView>
  <Button fx:id="btnIngresar" layoutX="186.0" layoutY="282.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#Ingresar" text="Ingresar" />
  <Label layoutX="178.0" layoutY="71.0" text="Usuario" textFill="WHITE">
     <font>
        <Font size="20.0" />
     </font>
  </Label>
  <Label layoutX="162.0" layoutY="186.0" text="Contraseña" textFill="WHITE">
     <font>
        <Font size="20.0" />
     </font>
  </Label>
  <TextField fx:id="txtUsuario" layoutX="138.0" layoutY="112.0" />
  <PasswordField fx:id="txtContraseña" layoutX="138.0" layoutY="233.0" />


     </children>
   </AnchorPane>
```

IngresoApp.java que posee el metodo para logearse

```
     public class IngresoApp {
        private StringProperty usuario;
        private StringProperty contraseña;

        public PreparedStatement instruccion;
        public ResultSet resultado;

        public IngresoApp(String usuario, String contraseña) { 
        this.usuario = new SimpleStringProperty(usuario);
        this.contraseña = new SimpleStringProperty(contraseña);
       }

       public IngresoApp() {
       throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");     
       }



       //Metodos atributo: usuario
       public String getUsuario() {
       return usuario.get();
      }
      public void setUsuario(String usuario) {
      this.usuario = new SimpleStringProperty(usuario);
      }
      public StringProperty UsuarioProperty() {
      return usuario;
     }
     //Metodos atributo: contraseña
     public String getContraseña() {
     return contraseña.get();
     }
     public void setContraseña(String contraseña) {
     this.contraseña = new SimpleStringProperty(contraseña);
     }
     public StringProperty ContraseñaProperty() {
     return contraseña;
     }

     public int ingresarUs(Connection connection) {  

    try{
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario = ? and contraseña = ?";

    instruccion = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
    instruccion.setString(1, usuario.get());
    instruccion.setString(2, contraseña.get());
    resultado = instruccion.executeQuery();




    }catch(Exception e){
     e.printStackTrace();
     }
        return 0;
     }
```

Conexion.java

```
    public class Conexion {
       private Connection connection;


       private  String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydb";
       private String usuario = "root";
       private String contraseña = ""; //cambiar contra si no funciona

       public Connection getConnection() {
        return connection;
       }

       public void setConnection(Connection connection) {
       this.connection = connection;
       }

       public void establecerConexion(){
       try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, usuario, contraseña);

       } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
       } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
       }
       }

       public void cerrarConexion(){
       try {
        connection.close();
      } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
```

AppController donde instancio un objecto de tipo IngresoApp que posee el metodo de login:

```
public class AppController implements Initializable {
    @FXML
    public TextField txtUsuario;

    @FXML
    public PasswordField txtContraseña;

    @FXML
    public Button btnIngresar;


    private Conexion connection;

   @Override
   public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

   }

   @FXML
   public void Ingresar(ActionEvent event) {
     IngresoApp iA= new IngresoApp(
        txtUsuario.getText(),
        txtContraseña.getText());
     connection.establecerConexion();
     int result= iA.ingresarUs(connection.getConnection());
     connection.cerrarConexion();

     if(result ==1){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Ingreso exitoso");
     }else{
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Ingreso Fallido");
    }
}

}
```

Lo que sucede cuando ejecuto en el netbean es que me sale una Exception:

```
     Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
     at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1774)
     at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
     at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
     at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
     at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
     at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
     at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
     at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
     at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
     at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
     at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
     at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
     at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
     at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
     at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
     at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8413)
     at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
     at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
     at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
     at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
     at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
     at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
     at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
     at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
     at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
     at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
     at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
     at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
     at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
     at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
     at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
     at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
     at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
     at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
     at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
     at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
     at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
     at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
     at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:380)
     at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:294)
     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
     at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$354(GlassViewEventHandler.java:416)
     at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
     at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:415)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1769)
... 48 more
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at login.AppController.Ingresar(AppController.java:41)
... 58 more
```

Desde la linea 41 a 43 en el AppControlleresta:

```
   connection.establecerConexion();
    int result= iA.ingresarUs(connection.getConnection());
    connection.cerrarConexion();
```

Comprobe la conexion a la DB con otro proyecto y conectó, no veo entonces que ocasiona la exception, por favor ayudeme quien pueda.